# loading dynamically created content dynamically with .load function

Tags: jquery, ajax

My question is something ive been looking into for a little while but every time i mix the words "dynamic" and .load()" i get all the wrong(or right) results so ill try to be as clear as possible.

Say for example that i have **2 pages, index page, and an about us page**. I know that with jQuery and `.load()` function, i can make a request to another document (the about us page for example), and load the about us pages' content as a whole into the index etc...and i can even be more specific with something like

.load("url here" #content div id specifically from the loaded about us page i want to bring into index.)

My question is, what happens when the content you are loading into index from the about us page is **also** being dynamically created??

So say for example that i have a WordPress custom template where pretty much ALL the content is dynamically generated. In the about us page that is generated by WordPress and a DB for example, if the inner content div in the about us page has this `<?php echo bloginfo('url');?>`  inside it which will print the websites URL on the page **(say XYZ.com)**, when called via AJAX with .load() into the index, will i get the un-ran code, or will it process like normal and i get XYZ.com

Comment: did you try it? i think it would process normally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it'll be processed normally, first it'll be generated on the server, then the generated html (the responseText) will be sent back in your page. The same way you do the direct call to a php page which will be generated server-side.